# Working with css before selector

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to overlap one image over another and make a circular image out of them.

[image]

```
    <span onclick="someFunction()" id="swatch_123456" class="slider-color-swatches" style="background-image: url(anyImage.png);"></span>

.slider-color-swatches{
    position: relative;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.slider-color-swatches::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url('anyOtherIamge.pnenter image description hereg');
    left: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200%;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

[Here are the images as to what I want to do and where Iam able to get so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClzE7.png)

Comment: can you post a fiddle of your code?

Comment: Try this http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/mask-image/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..
may be worked..

```
{
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display: block;` to your `::before` element.
Doing this will put your width and height into effect.

Also, adding `margin: auto;` will keep it centered.

**Example:**

```
.slider-color-swatches::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    background-image: url('anyOtherIamge.pnenter image description hereg');
    left: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200%;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg); }
```

If you want to try a different method, take a look at [clipping and masking](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/)!